# Adding a third Mod Rewrite - mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

guys. I'm trying to add a third rewrite condition in my .htaccess. The problem is, I have no idea how to add another one. So if anyone has a good in-depth tutorial on it I would be greatful.

Anyway back to business. Here is my current code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The above as you might see removes the .php extensions and makes all files that don't exist go to users(IE: website.com/user goes to user's profile page).

So now I need to add one for the forum. I would like it rewrite like *"website.com/Group/Category/Thread"*.

Is this even possible, or do I need to lower my expectations for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I remember posting this answer :)

Anyway you can create a new rule on top of previous rules like this (and replace `/Group/Category/Thread` with whatever you have) :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^forum/?$ /Group/Category/Thread [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Looks, good. How do I dynamically change the Group Category and thread though? Like per page?

Comment: Pls provide details on what you want to do as your statement: `So now I need to add one for the forum. I would like it rewrite like "website.com/Group/Category/Thread".` is not entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert more rules. Given that you want these rules to be matched before your final catch-all to user.php, you should place them before that final rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# match forum, forum/group, forum/group/category and forum/group/category/thread urls
RewriteRule ^forum/?$ forum.php?group=$1&category=$2&thread=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/?$ forum.php?group=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ forum.php?group=$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ forum.php?group=$1&category=$2&thread=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```